# Filter chain halted as force SSL rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku, procfile

So my app in production has totally crashed with this message:

```
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f766547ea18@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb:65> rendered or redirected
```

I've done some research online and so far this seems to happen mostly in local dev mode when the port is lost. But I'm not sure why this would be happening in my Heroku app... for context the code has not changed, and it was working fine as of 30 minutes ago. I'm using CloudFlare, but I checked that the bare `your-app-name.herokuapp.com` is also broken with the same error.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: OK a `heroku restart` fixed this... but would love to know root cause in case it happens again...

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error but on my development environment in rails 4.0 (because of an controller with force_ssl on it).

I solved this using the **thin web server with ssl support**, like so:

1. Add the thin gem to my `Gemfile` on the development group:

```ruby
    group :development do
      gem 'thin'
    end
```

2. Run bundle install on your termnal:

   `bundle install`
3. Start thin with ssl support on terminal:

   `bundle exec thin start --ssl`
4. Access the page **via https** on your web browser:

   **The protocol need to be https at the beginning**, otherwise you can get an empty response. (**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**)

   `https://localhost:3000/`

   If you get your connection refused (**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**) you'll need to define the loopback ip address on the server params:

   `bundle exec thin start --ssl -a 127.0.0.1`
5. You'll get an privacy error, jus click on **Advanced** and on **Go to localhost (not safe)**

Sorry my image is in pt-br:
[image]

6. It's done! You'll get an self-signed https connection on localhost in development mode ;)